# is there any alternative to < object > tag in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

is there any alternative  to < object > tag in google chrome?

```
<div id="topBar">
<a href ="#" onclick="load_home()"> HOME </a>
</div>
<div id ="content"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function load_home(){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="home.html" ></object>';
}
```

it works fine on firefox but not in google chorme. why? any solution? it shows "no plug-in available to display this content". now my question is how to available plug-in to display the html page?

Comment: This is what `<iframe>` elements are for.

Comment: You've got `type="type/html"` That should be `type="text/html"` Then it will work fine in Chrome.

Comment: wow! thanks thanks thanks! you are right! it wooooorkkksssss :).  this code drove me crazy all day. I was dying to find the solution.  Thank you so much. Such a silly mistake I hardly noticed! Now finally I can finish my project work. :) @Alohci

Answer (score 5):

Use an `iframe` instead of the `<object>` tag. `<object>` tags do not reliably work cross-browser, and are mostly used for Flash and sometimes Java applets. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for more on `iframes`.

Comment: I'd say they are used for Flash much more often than Java applets which are used less and less nowadays.

Comment: @ThiefMaster good point. I will add it. Sorry, I'm a Java programmer, and I seem to be very alone in still liking applets >.<